# Existence of Galerkin Approximation for Navier-Stokes equations

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, galerkin-methods

In some existence proof for the stationary incompressible Navier-Stokes equations I came across the following Lemma:

For $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $\psi _k \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ for $k=1,...,m$ with

\begin{equation}
(\psi _k, \psi _l)= \delta_{kl}
\end{equation}

we consider the system

\begin{equation}
\nu (\nabla w, \nabla \psi _k) = F_k(\xi),\ \ \ k=1,...,m \ \ \ (1)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
w = \sum _{k=1}^m \xi _k \psi _k \ \ \ (2)
\end{equation}

with $\nu > 0,$ $\xi = (\xi_1,...,\xi_m)\in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $F:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ continuous. If there are $c>0$ and $0< a < \nu$ satisfying

\begin{equation}
F(\xi)\cdot \xi \leq c\|w\|_{1,2} + a \|w\|_{1,2}^2 \ \ \ (3)
\end{equation}

then $(1)$, $(2)$ admits a solution $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

Now it further says that condition (3) may be generalized, but unfortunately no references are mentioned. In particular, I would be interested in a version of the Lemma where $a < \nu$ can be relaxed or with some higher order terms on the right hand side, but I do not what to look for. Can somebody tell me where I might find results like this?